# Worksheet_Change to hide rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, hide

I have a macro that is supposed to hide a row in excel when a value of a given cell is "ODD" (the word, not an odd number). I've tried two different formats; neither gives any visible error but neither hides the row.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

If target.Address <> "$B$2" Then Exit Sub
    ElseIf Range("B2").Value = "ODD" Then
        Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

The other code I had is:

```
Select Case Range("B2").Value
    Case Is = "ODD": Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Else: Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select
```

It was modified from a more advanced case statement and I just left it that way at first.

Comment: Where are you storing the Change Sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Rows("5:5")` would be better as `Rows(5)`. The method you used would be better as `Range("5:5")`.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = (UCase(Target.Value) = "ODD")
    End If
End Sub
```

Since comparing B2 to *ODD* already produces a *True* or *False*, you can dispense with the `If/Else/End If`. Text comparisons in VBA are usually case sensitive, hence the need for `UCase` to force case insensitivity.

Comment: Glad you got sorted out. To clarify, the `Rows(5)` vs. `Rows("5:5")` vs. `Range("5:5")` is really more of a preference. Any of them will reference row 5 correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a key code line `If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then` Try the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell   As Range
    Set cell = Range("B2")
    If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("B2").Value = "ODD" Then
            Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your Change Sub is stored in the Worksheet module of the Sheet you want this to perform on.  Then you have a slight syntax error with your If Statements:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    If target is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If target.Address <> "$B$2" Then Exit Sub
        If Range("B2").Value = "ODD" Then
            Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

End Sub
```

When you put the `If...Then...` on one line, it actually closes the `If` (no `End If` needed)  Also, I flipped your True and False statements to match your requirement in your question.